# How to trigger terraform deployment that resides in a separate repo with Azure Pipelines?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, multiple-repositories

We have a nodejs application that has azure-pipelines file where it gets triggered by a PR and builds the image and sends it to ECR on AWS. We also have all our terraform AWS infrastructure code on a separate repo.

We want the terraform deployment to be triggered once the pipeline on the application repo finishes and image is pushed to the registry. What is a good way to achieve this?

Open to suggestions and recommendations. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [repository resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops) to checkout code from other repositories. From there, just run whatever steps you need to apply terraform scripts.

There's also [TriggerBuild](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=benjhuser.tfs-extensions-build-tasks) task that you could use if you want to have a separate pipeline for that terraform.

Comment: Thanks! So it seems Azure Repos Git is what I need to use as repository resource. We are also using Terraform Workspaces as dev, preprod, prod. So we need to set it in a way a PR or a manual trigger runs a specific workspace. With that do we also need to have a pipeline yaml on terraform's repository if we go the way with repository resource? Or we would need that if we go the [TriggerBuild](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=benjhuser.tfs-extensions-build-tasks) method?

Comment: I went ahead and tried the multi repo checkout method it checks out the repo where terraform code is. But is this a good way to do this? What if We create two pipelines one on application repo and one on terraform repo. The application pipeline goes and triggers the terraform pipeline passing to it image name as variable etc?

Comment: There's no good or wrong here, it all depends on what better fits your needs, is easier to understand and maintain, etc. Personally, I'd create two pipelines and have one trigger the other. This way, you could trigger the terraform infra independently (i.e. if there are some infra changes that do not involve app deployment).

Comment: BTW, here's what [terraform guide](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/state/workspaces.html#when-to-use-multiple-workspaces) says about workspaces: "In particular, organizations commonly want to create a strong separation between multiple deployments of the same infrastructure serving different development stages (e.g. staging vs. production) or different internal teams. In this case, the backend used for each deployment often belongs to that deployment, with different credentials and access controls. Named workspaces are not a suitable isolation mechanism for this scenario."

Comment: Thank you! Indeed having terraform in a separate pipeline would allow us to trigger it independently (which we will need to). About workspaces the first case mentioned in the guide looks very similar to our case hence why using workspaces. We have a very modular and dynamic terraform infra code where we will need to deploy it to different environments either exactly the same or enabling/disabling any resource depending on environment, we used CloudPosse's modules for this.